# Using UIGestureRecognizer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to subclass `UIButton` with `UIGestureRecognizer` to add different targets to the button, depending on the initial axis along which the drag is moving. I've gotten as far as this:

```
class restrictedDragButton: UIButton {
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translationInView(self)
        if abs(translation.y) > abs(translation.x) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me the error `Overriding method with selector 'gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:' has incompatible type '(UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Bool'`. I've added the delegate to my view controller, so I'm not sure what else to do.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to say something like:

```
if myButton.gestureRecognizerShouldBegin() {  // returns vertical
    myButton.addTarget(...)  // vertical drag selector
} else {
    myButton.addTarget(...)  // horizontal drag selector
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

should be

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

So `UIGestureRecognizer`, not `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. You can find out more about the method in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:).